# How do I add print button in Joomla list view.?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, view

I have created my business logic in model, but in view part I'm not so expert of how to use JHTML.
Can anyone tell me how can I add a print button in joomla list view?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at com_content to see how it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you talk about the frontend or backend... if you are in the Joomla! backend you can create a custom toolbar button in your view.html.php

```
$bar = & JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
```

$bar->appendButton( 'Print', 'print32', 'Print', 'index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=yourviewname&tmpl=component&print=1' );

The second argument is an image if you want a custom image you need to add extra styles in a css file:

```
.icon-32-print32 {
    background-image: url(../images/print32.png);
```

}

In your view check for the print variable in the url and put a button if present, for example:

```
<?php if(JRequest::getVar('print', 0, 'get') == 1) : ?><a href="#" onclick="window.print();" >Click for Printing</a><?php endif; ?>
```

The toolbar button opens your list without the joomla template but check if your admin template has a component.php file in the template root.

If you are in the frontend check this explanation in the Joomla! Docs https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_print_pop-up_functionality_to_a_component

Comment: yes i'm talking about back-end and yes thanks